# required argument on Column error on flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Error saying 1 required argument(s) expected but 0 found. On every flutter project the Column gives an error. Opened up a new flutter project on VS code and still gives the same error.

have updated dart, uninstalled flutter and dart on VS and installed again, my flutter doctor runs completely fine.

import `package:flutter/material.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center  ,
      children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> 1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the additional required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code, replace yours with mine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: same error 1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the additional required arguments.

Comment: I have updated the answer, kindly replace all of your code with mine.

Comment: Can you please show the screenshot of the error? I will be able to assist you better.

Comment: The code is 100% correct, there must be some issue with the IDE, try to restart it or you can fill a bug issue on Github if that didn't help.

Comment: thank you, I've shut down my laptop and restarted the IDE and doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: Then the best place is to file an issue on Github.

Comment: Try to rollback to a previous version of flutter